# Tomcat RestCsrfPreventionFilter - cannot get CSRF nonce

Tags: tomcat, csrf

I have enabled the RestCsrfPreventionFilter in Tomcat for my REST API. At a high level, it is working mostly right. Any endpoints that modify my application's state (ie, POST, PUT, etc) get rejected due to not having a CSRF nonce in the request.

The problem I'm running into is I can't seem to get the CSRF nonce to begin with. No request that I have tried has returned this token to me. If I can't get the CSRF nonce from the server, how am I supposed to then return it?

I've been through what feels like every piece of documentation out there. I just cannot see any indication of how I'm supposed to get the nonce to begin with.

Filter Configuration:

```
<filter>
        <filter-name>RestCSRF</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.RestCsrfPreventionFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>denyStatus</param-name>
            <param-value>403</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>pathsAcceptingParams</param-name>
            <param-value>/rest/*</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>RestCSRF</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

Comment: How have you tried to get the nonce?

Comment: Were you able to figure this out?  I am using Tomcat 8.5 and have the same issue.  Requesting a nonce by sending a GET request with the header "X-CSRF-Token" set to "FETCH"

Answer (score 0):

The solution here was simple. Any valid GET request with the header X-CSRF-TOKEN=fetch will return the nonce in a response header of the same name. Then I set X-CSRF-TOKEN=[NONCE] in POST or other requests going forward.